# unexpected response code 401 for URL

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.murarilal.volley;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RequestQueue queue;
    ListView listView;
    List<Hero> heroList;

    private String url="API_KEY";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        home();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        heroList = new ArrayList<>();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ArticleActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("description",url);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void home()
    {
        JsonObjectRequest request =new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));

                    JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("articles");

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        Hero hero=new Hero( (String) array.getJSONObject(i).get("title"),(String) array.getJSONObject(i).get("urlToImage"));
                        heroList.add(hero);
                    }

                    ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(heroList, getApplicationContext());
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
                , new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        queue.add(request);
    }
}


package com.example.murarilal.volley;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class ArticleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_article);
        String url="https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&apiKey=59b308aec9f242fe98b527ab9ba93199";

        WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        Intent intent=getIntent();
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(url,null,intent.getStringExtra("description"),"text/html","UTF-8");
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=techcrunch&apiKey=d6eaad863cc640a7a6864d18196bea9e

I'm trying to fetch data from the above **url** but it returns an unexpected 401 response code. I checked the url and it's perfectly valid but the my code gives this error. when the emulator starts it shows blank activity

**this the log error**

> 11-17 16:20:20.804 14350-14350/com.example.murarilal.volley
>   W/System.err: com.android.volley.AuthFailureError 11-17 16:20:20.804
>   14350-14350/com.example.murarilal.volley W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:141)
>   11-17 16:20:20.804 14350-14350/com.example.murarilal.volley
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:105)

Comment: where are you getting error in webview or the jsonobject request

Comment: General rule of thumb, don't post API keys in public forums

Comment: **in the logs**

Comment: dude i know in the log you are getting error but when while using in which activity

Comment: that is what i m saying its showing blank activity

Comment: @devesh i am being clear here, you have posted 2 activity source code in which activity are you getting error

Comment: is the url used in the code is proper? its https://newsapi.org/v1 or https://newsapi.org/v2

Comment: yes its correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RequestQueue queue;
    ListView listView;
    List<Hero> heroList;

    private String url="https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=techcrunch&apiKey=d6eaad863cc640a7a6864d18196bea9e";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        home();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        heroList = new ArrayList<>();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

               /* Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ArticleActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("description",url);
                startActivity(intent);*/
            }
        });
    }

    public void home()
    {
        JsonObjectRequest request =new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));

                    JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("articles");

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        Hero hero=new Hero( (String) array.getJSONObject(i).get("title"),(String) array.getJSONObject(i).get("urlToImage"));
                        Log.d("title ", String.valueOf(array.getJSONObject(i).get("title")));
                        Log.d("urlToImage ", String.valueOf(array.getJSONObject(i).get("urlToImage")));
                        heroList.add(hero);
                    }

                    ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(heroList, getApplicationContext());
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
                , new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        queue.add(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `URLConnection` instead of volley.
401 indicates of have Unauthorized access to the given URL

Answer (score 0):

I tried both api V1 And V2 with volley and got status code 200 and the data matches with the data shown when the request is made from a browser.

To help Can you add Logs and post it over here

```
  , new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
             Log.d(TAG,error.networkResponse.toString());
             error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I used your api keys and again got status code 200 and the data matches with the data shown when the request is made from a browser.

I know this sounds silly but clean project and then install the apk.

Also can you post this  error.printStackTrace(); as well

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this line in your gradle file.

I've implemented your code, the data is being called properly.

```html
 compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
```

Comment: i included above gradle file but getting same error

Comment: just copy paste my edited code separately and check your log